# How do I get my ETH back? Transaction cancelled but ETH are gone :/

Tags: transactions, gas, nft, coinbase

On Dec 18th I connected my Coinbase wallet to buy Adidas NFT on opensea.io
It did not work several times but then it seemed to work. But finally I gut the confirmation that Transaktion was cancelled. Since then my ETH are gone (or maybe stuck) ;(
Contacted Coinbase Support several times but they send standard answer without any helpful content. They write the same each time…
This is my transaction hash:

0xa73fbf6292ff538810c9399df1b08a05dee5bf0835527aaf06f58866f4d3307a

### Do you have any ideas how I get back my ETH?

18.12.2021
Tried to buy Adidas NFT with Coinbase wallet
Transaction 1:
EUR amount 3.314,25 €/
0,92 ETH
Status: Fail
To:
Contract 0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b (OpenSea)
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
Value:
0.92 Ether ($3,749.34) - [CANCELLED]
Transaction Fee:
0.0036998577 Ether ($15.08)

Comment: The sender account has 5.6ether , when a transaction fail then the ether will not be sent! (Only fee) how many ether did you have before the transaction!?

Answer (score 2):

The transactions was reverted, which means that everything is rolled back and it's like the transactions never happened. Your account has received the Eth back (or, in fact, it never even left the account).

If your wallet still shows the old balance, your wallet is not synchronized properly, or there's some problem with it. The blockchain has the right data, your wallet simply may have showing the right data for some reason.

You can see the right balance for example here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xf59402106623745731a269a9050764a4e1ef99e3

Comment: sir i also have one problem i want to send erc20 tokens using javascript  not etherium i look on docs of metamask the script example which i have seen is only send etherium i want to send usdc i want accept usdc coin in my website i have ask this question on stackoverflow i have also personally texted you on telegram and also sended you request on linked in please help me sir

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, reverted transactions do not change the state in the blockchain (except the gas used by your transaction), and thus the ethers in your account were not sent anywhere.

I see you had ~9.69 ether sent into your account on [November 17th, 2020](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x705193e6e34922a5e3ce2a40b2925f51d9cb716a7ec1f6c4fa3e0818d5fa1a23).

You then swapped ~2 ether for 855 MC (Merit Circle) [about a month ago](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8ca499a364ca00e30f2b61344dd23f5335776e99979188850801df87a93f97fc). Your balance is now about ~7.69 ether.

Finally, there are two transactions ([first](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x70b94f7b326138ab3c2460c4f523ae0d924cf37ce5ed83d525af2ddcd32c7cd6) and [second](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd0eb5348e3c49e3cd85ea716473f9e0f59de69cf50c70430891024fb5e9aa4cf)) in which you send 1 ether to another account, and that would account for the difference you are seeing (~7.69 ether vs ~5.69 ether).

This other account received the MC you previously swapped and 2 ether, and sent it all to a Binance hot wallet. I think that it was lost since those wallets are only meant to send tokens and not receive, and the deposit wallets are generated per user by Binance and all major exchanges.

If the account that sent the MC to Binance wallet was yours, I'd try contacting them and trying to recover the balance from their wallet into your Binance account.